# How to ShowAllData before closing excel file using vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code which shows all data (clearinging filters) and saves the file before closing. Based on the other questions asked, I used Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean). But it does not run the sub.

I tried two ways.

Method1:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Call FilterDataWhenClosing
End Sub


In a separate Module:

Sub FilterDataWhenClosing()

If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData    
ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Method 2:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
Range("B5").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

None of the methods work. When I filter the data and close the file, the filers are present when I open the file again. I am trying to make sure the filters get cleared before closing the file and saving it. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way?

Comment: Did you put the sub "Workbook_BeforeClose" in a Module or in the "ThisWorkbook"-Tab?

Comment: In a Module. I was trying various ways and tried putting the sub is a class module as well. That did not work either.

Comment: In the VBA Editor you should see two folder "Microsoft Excel Objects" and "Modules" can you open "Microsoft Excel Objects" -> "ThisWorkbook" and paste the sub "Workbook_BeforeClose" in there. The "ThisWorkbook" represents the workbook object and checks on closing if the sub "Workbook_BeforeClose" is there and runs it. It doesn't check modules

Comment: This comment helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

### A Workbook BeforeClose

- `.AutoFilterMode` only means that auto filtering is turned on.
- `.FilterMode` means that there are filters applied.

**`ThisWorkbook` Module**

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    ClearFiltersBeforeClosing Me.ActiveSheet ' or e.g. Me.Worksheets("Sheet1")
End Sub
```

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ClearFiltersBeforeClosing(ByVal Sheet As Object)

    If Not TypeOf Sheet Is Worksheet Then Exit Sub ' not a worksheet
    
    With Sheet
        If .FilterMode Then
            .ShowAllData
            .Parent.Save
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```